# How to copy relative symbolic links and keep targets

Tags: linux, symbolic-link

My situation has 2 directories: /blah/d01 and /blah/d02

```
$ls -l /blah/d01
a/
b/
c/
fa -> a
fb -> b
fc -> c
```

and I want to copy fa, fb, fc to /blah/d02, and as a result:

```
$ls -l /blah/d02
fa -> ../d01/a
fb -> ../d01/b
fc -> ../d01/c
```

the point is, I want to do something like cp --{some magic attr} /blah/d01/f* /blah/d02/ to make this happen.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I settled with a bash script:

```
#! /bin/bash
for i in $@; do echo $i && [ -L $i ] && ln -s $(dirname $i)/$(readlink $i) $(basename $i); done
```

which make newlinks based on old ones(make sure that they use relative path)

**UPDATE AGAIN**

I found my last script works but the link path would be awkwardly long(full with strange relative paths) after copy symlinks from a to b and from b to c, so I added [something to cleanup relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564634/bash-convert-absolute-path-into-relative-path-given-a-current-directory), and the script ends:

```
#! /bin/bash
function relpath {
  source=$1
  target=$2

  common_part=$source
  back=
  while [ "${target#$common_part}" = "${target}" ]; do
    common_part=$(dirname $common_part)
    back="../${back}"
  done

  echo ${back}${target#$common_part/}
}

for i in $@; do echo $i && [ -L $i ] && ln -s $(relpath $PWD $(readlink -f $i)); done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As those symlinks are created w/o full qualified path, that's a thing hard to do with `cp`. But you could rather create new ones at the target:

```
for i in *; do [ -L $i ] && cd blah && ln -s ../$i $i && cd -; done
```

Short explanation:

- `for i in *`: Loop over the list of files/directories in the currend location
- `do`: encapsulate what has to be done
- `[ -L $i ] &&`: only continue if the current entry is a symbolic link
- `cd blah && ln -s ../$i $i && cd -`: change to blah and create symlinks to the original location

That's not yet exactly what you want (as it symlinks the symlinks). So we will modify it a bit:

```
for i in *; do [ -L $i ] && cd blah && ln -s ../$(readlink ../$i) $i && cd -; done
```

The added construct `$(readlink ../$i)` evaluates the object the link points to, and places the result there instead. Et voila -- the result is what you were looking for.

Note that I simplified your request a little (making it as if you'd just want to copy the symlinks to a subdirectory), so it is easier to follow. You have to adjust it either, as I do not assume your real directory is called `blah` :)

Comment: @lzzy that's really decent of you, thanks! maybe I should save this script :D

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use full path instead relative path as

```
fx -> /full/path/to/x
```

So when you copy link it will always show x.

Comment: Doing this your way is acceptable, despite the trouble to provide abs path when ln ... thanks

Comment: And sadly, I just find out that I want it relative, to work under nfs, too...

Comment: not just that but relative is kinda needed in removable disks too whose mountpoint can change